# How to namespace / use a php file with multiple classes in it. Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, soundcloud, laravel-5

I am trying to use the Soundcloud API for PHP. Which fan be viewed [here](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud).

I changed the name of `Soundcloud.php` to `Services_Soundcloud.php` since that is the class name of file.

I also changed the name of `Version.php` in the Services folder to `Service_Soundcloud_Version.php` to match the class name.

My problem is with `Excepetion.php`. It has 4 classes in one PHP file. How do I namespace / use the files? Should I split these up into separate files to use?

Comment: Did you check this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet i actually tried doing that. PhpStorm started freaking out though. I'll tinker with it again.

Comment: I'm not saying that it would be a good solution though. Splitting your exceptions in several files would be way better imo.

Comment: You can either split each exception into a different file or just leave the `require_once` [line #1, Soundcloud.php]

Comment: Or maybe take a look at this package: [njasm/soundcloud](https://github.com/njasm/soundcloud). At least from a coding standard point of view it looks a lot better

Comment: @Gal I tried leaving it as is, but Laravel throws an exception saying it can't find it.

Comment: @lukasgeiter thanks for finding that. I am now using that instead. Much easier to follow and use.